# Make QuerySelectField selected data object into a literal value

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a part of my application in which an admin can register a user. I have a registration form in which one of the elements of the form is a `QuerySelectField` that gets a list of locations from db that the user can be linked too. I'm able to display the `QuerySelectField` with the correct information but upon submitting the form I get an error

> Sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object "Site" is not legal as a SQL literal value

This error populates when trying to query the database in my form Sites Model to find the name of the selected option in the `QuerySelectField` so that I can then store the ID of the particular site within a variable for further use.

I'm not sure how to make the object a literal value that sqlalchemy can read. I tried wrapping it in a str() but that didn't do a thing. I'm a noob by the way so I'm still trying to get a grasp on certain elements of flask.

This is my Form for what I'm trying to accomplish

```
def site():
    return Sites.query.all()

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), 
Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=

[DataRequired(), Email()])
        password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
        confirm_pass = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators= 
   [DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
        admin_status = BooleanField('Check for Admin Status')
        sitechoices = QuerySelectField(query_factory=site, allow_blank=False, 
   get_label='sitename')
```

Here is the route info in my routes.py

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def register():
    forms = RegistrationForm()
    if forms.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_pw = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(forms.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        siteid = Sites.query.filter_by(sitename=forms.sitechoices.data).first().id
        user = User(site = forms.sitechoices.data, username = forms.username.data, email = forms.email.data, 
        password = hashed_pw, adminstatus= forms.admin_status.data, sitelink=siteid)
        db.create_all()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"{form.username.data} has been added!")
        return redirect(url_for('dash'))
    return render_template('register.html', name = 'login', form=forms)
```

Here is the template info that is needed:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{form.sitechoices}}
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve site names from model within queryselectfield and be able to register a user with that selected option.

Comment: Could you do a print (forms.sitechoices.data) when submitting the form. I think this value is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes so I have added the print statement and this does print out the desired site name. I think this is working considering I have __repr__(self) function that returns the actual self.sitename in the model. Not sure how to correlate that information to the form.sitechoices.data.

Comment: As far as I understand is that the object is returned, so what you need to use is form.sitechoices.data.sitename to save a submitted form.

Comment: Your amazing, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you. I guess the error is self explanatory. I'm still trying to understand why it's returning an object instead of the actual data, but in the meantime thank you!

Comment: Well, look into the documentation ;). No just kidding, I have been working on an issue in my code with this field recently so I understand the inner working by now. Even the all() in your query kind of surprises me, that doesnt even work here.

Comment: Ha will do, thank you sir. I was surprised the all() worked as well; I had just 'Sites.query' but I added the .all() to see if it that would do anything, I was kind of just shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a queryselectfield the object is returned, so what you need to use is form.sitechoices.data.sitename to save a submitted form

Answer (score 0):

I use Flask, Blueprint, WTForms 3.0, SQLAlchemy, Bootstrap 4 - and the following syntax works for me ...

**FORMS.py**

```
class IndicatorForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        csrf = False

    ind_id = IntegerField('indid', id='indid')
    topic = QuerySelectField('Topic',query_factory=lambda: Indicator.query.group_by("topic"), allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'Topic', get_pk=lambda a: a.id, get_label='topic')
    subtopic1 = QuerySelectField('SubTopic',query_factory=lambda: Indicator.query.group_by("subtopic1"), allow_blank=True, blank_text=u'SubTopic', get_pk=lambda a: a.id, get_label='subtopic1')
```

**routes.py**

```
@blueprint.route('/newind_edit', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def newind_edit():

    form = IndicatorForm(request.form) 

    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        indid = request.form['ind_id']
        Indicator.query.filter_by(id=indid).update(dict(
            id=ind_id,
            topic = form.topic.name.topic,     # <== this is the selected value
            subtopic1 = form.subtopic1.name.subtopic1   #  <== add as many pull-downs as you like
            ))    
        db.session.commit()
```